# How to add digest from sha256 to string in flutter?

Tags: flutter, cryptography

I'm passing password into sha256. I successfully create sha256 and can also print it. The problem begins when I'm trying to convert digest.bytes into a string and append it.

```
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

var url = "http://example_api.php?";
url += '&hash=';

// hash the password
var bytes = utf8.encode(password);
var digest = sha256.convert(bytes);
print("Digest as hex string: $digest");

url += String.fromCharCodes(digest.bytes);
```

This is printed: *Digest as hex string: 03ac674216f3e15c761ee1a5e255f067953623c8b388b4459e13f978d7c846f4*

This is appended to url: *¬gBóá\vá¥âUðg6#È³´Eùx×ÈFô*

What am I doing wrong? I also tried utf8.decode method but using it gives me an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you print `digest`, the `print` method will call `digest.toString()`, which is implemented to return a string of the digest bytes using a hexadecimal representation. If you want the same thing you have several options:

- Call `digest.toString()` explicitly (or implicitly)

```dart
final digestHex = digest.toString(); // explicitly
final digestHex = '$digest';         // implicitly
```

- Map the byte array to its hexadecimal equivalent

```dart
final digestHex = digest.bytes.map((b) => b.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join();
```

- Use the [convert](https://pub.dev/packages/convert) package (this is what the crypto package does)

```dart
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';

...

final digestHex = hex.encode(digest.bytes);
```

---

The reason you are getting an error using `utf8.decode` is that your digest isn't an encoded UTF-8 string but a list of bytes that for all intents and purposes are completely random. You are trying to directly convert the bytes into a string, and doing so is easier if you can assume that they already represent a valid string. With the byte output from a hashing algorithm, though, you cannot safely make such an assumption.

However, if for some reason you still want to use this option, use the second optional parameter for `utf8.decode` to force it to try and decode the bytes anyway:

```dart
final digestString = utf8.decode(bytes, allowMalformed: true);
```

For reference, a byte list of `[1, 255, 47, 143, 6, 80, 33, 202]` results in "�/�P!�" where "�" represents an invalid/control character. You do not want to use this option, especially where the string will become part of a URL (as it's virtually guaranteed that the resulting string will not be web-safe).

Answer (score 1):

For the hexadecimal representation of a Digest object, please explicitly call `Digest.toString()` (though in formatted strings, i.e. `"url${digest}"`, this is done for you implicitly).

I'm frankly not familiar with `String.fromCharCode`, but [I think it's looking for UTF-16 and not UTF-8 bits](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/String/String.fromCharCodes.html).  I wrote a terminal example to show this, and how the outputs differ.

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

void main() {

  const String password = "mypassword";

  // hash the password
  var bytes = utf8.encode(password);
  var digest = sha256.convert(bytes);

  // different formats
  var bytesDigest = digest.bytes;
  var hexDigest = digest.toString();

  String url = "http://example_api.php?hash=";

  print(url + hexDigest);
  print(url + String.fromCharCodes(bytesDigest));

}
```

Output:

```
> dart test.dart
http://example_api.php?hash=89e01536ac207279409d4de1e5253e01f4a1769e696db0d6062ca9b8f56767c8
http://example_api.php?hash=à6¬ ry@Ö,©¸õggÈ
```

Comment: Ah damn, I don't know how this site works =) TY fren